# Completeness of first-order logic with interpreted function symbols

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

A paper I'm reading asserts that "there is no sound and complete procedure for validity of first-order logic formulas of linear arithmetic with uninterpreted function symbols". By this we mean formulas like $f(x) + 1 > y$, where $+$ and $>$ are interpreted by Presburger arithmetic, and $f$ is uninterpreted. But how is this true? First-order logic is undecidable but complete. Presburger arithmetic is not finitely axiomatisable, but the axioms are recursively enumerable. Due to compactness of first-order logic, we can reduce the problem of finding a proof from the infinite axiom set to finding a proof from some finite subset of the axioms. And Godel's completeness theorem says we can always find a proof, if the formula is valid.

If this is true, then why would "first-order formulas of linear arithmetic with uninterpreted function symbols" (or any first-order formula, for that matter) not have a sound and complete procedure to check validity?

EDIT: The paper is: Ge, De Moura. "Complete instantiation for quantified formulas in
Satisfiability Modulo Theories". http://leodemoura.github.io/files/citr09.pdf. The quote is in the first page.

Comment: I don’t think I understand. You say validity in first order logic is undecidable, but your final paragraph seems to suggest you doubt this.

Comment: It is undecidable, but semidecidable. If $A \models \phi$, then $A \vdash \phi$, else the algorithm may not terminate. My question is: if this holds in general, how come it doesn't hold for "first-order formulas of linear arithmetic with uninterpreted function symbols"?

Comment: You should cite the paper you're reading. This would provide more context and allow others to read what is actually written. To be clear, you should *always* cite texts that you quote from.

Comment: Updated with citation

Answer (score 1):

This is a different meaning of the terms "sound" and "complete". When we say that a *proof system* is sound/complete with respect to a *semantics*, we mean that provability (in the proof system) implies/is implied by validity (in the semantics). This is *not* what's being discussed here.

Instead, when we have a *decision procedure*, here for validity of some formulas, we say it is "sound" if *when it terminates*, it terminates with the correct answer. It's "complete" if it always terminates. See slide 15 [here](http://www.decision-procedures.org/slides/basics-2x3.pdf).

The different meanings of these words are largely unconnected.